# How to trigger a Loader to re-render in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In below code i want to trigger a Re-Render of Loader so that the data is updated,but i am not sure how to do it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLoaderData, defer, Await } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Loader = () => {
    let fetch_data = fetchRequest('', 'GET');
    console.log("loading data");
    return defer({ loaderPromise: fetch_data });
};

export default function Home() {

    const loaderData = useLoaderData();

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <React.Suspense fallback={<PreLoader />}>

                <Await resolve={loaderData.loaderPromise}>
                    {(resolvedData) => {

                        if (resolvedData.type === "warning") {
                            throw new Error(resolvedData.msg);
                        }

                        let { coins_list, wallets_list } = resolvedData;

                        return (
                            <>
                               "JSX"
                               </>
                </Await>
            </React.Suspense>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried following

```
const [reloadData,setReloadData] = React.useState(false);

     React.useEffect(() => {
            if (reloadData) {
                navigate('.', { replace: true });
                setReloadData(false);
            }
        }, [reloadData, navigate]);
```

But not working as expected the url changes from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/index?

Comment: Check here https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-revalidator

Comment: Ok its seems nice but how can i trigger the React Suspense to show the fallback

Comment: "Ok its seems nice but how can i trigger the React Suspense to show the fallback" - You can't since the route is already loaded, so you'll need to use some other mechanism to conditionally render some loading UI. The [`useNavigation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation#navigationstate) hook may help here.

Comment: ok got it,thank you sou much can anyone post an answer so that i can accept it and close this quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `Route` component's [`shouldRevalidate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/should-revalidate) prop there are several  ways the route data is revalidated.

> There are several instances where data is revalidated, keeping your UI
> in sync with your data automatically:
>
> - After an [`action`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action) is called from a [`<Form>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/form).
> - After an [`action`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action) is called from a [`<fetcher.Form>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-fetcher)
> - After an [`action`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action) is called from [`useSubmit`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-submit)
> - After an [`action`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action) is called from a [`fetcher.submit`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-fetcher)
> - When an explicit revalidation is triggered via [`useRevalidator`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-revalidator)
> - When the [URL params](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) change for an already rendered route
> - When the URL Search params change
> - When navigating to the same URL as the current URL

The `useRevalidator` hook is the likely choice for your use case.

> This hook allows you to revalidate the data for any reason. React
> Router automatically revalidates the data after actions are called,
> but you may want to revalidate for other reasons like when focus
> returns to the window.

```js
import { useRevalidator } from "react-router-dom";

...

const revalidator = useRevalidator();

...

const callback = () => revalidator.revalidate();

...
```

Another trivial method is to initiate a navigation action to the current route, i.e. "navigating to the same URL as the current URL".

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const callback = () => navigate(".", { replace: true });

...
```